# Executing a child job on Talend based on DB table completion status

Tags: talend

I am working on a job design that will trigger a child job based on completion status that the job reads from the database.

If the return value from database is Y, then the child job should execute. If the return value from database in N, the job should sleep and look for the return value from database after 15 minutes. If the return value is Y, then the child job should execute, else it should sleep and this goes on loop.

I tried with the following design approach, but the job is stuck at tSleep

tSetGlobalVariable -> tLoop -> tRunJob (Child job1) -> tSleep -> tRunJob (Child job2)

tRunJob (Child job1) would fetch status if a particular job has completed or not from the database and would send the status back to run on a While loop. If the status is Y, ChildJob2 would run. If the status is N, it should sleep until the status changes to Y.

Comment: You say that "the job is stuck at tSleep" : the problem is with the tSleep ? If you remove the component, is the Loop working ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the component tWaitForSqlData which combine the scan, sleep and condition portions of your job.

The simplification should help you pinpoint where your problem is exactly.